# Group by year in Query in Teradata

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I have a query which needs to group by year.

**select distinct emp.id, emp.name, emp.joining_on  from employee;**

Output:

**id ----  name ----    joining_on**
1  -----  Tev -----  8/15/2020 10:30:52

2 -----   Sam -----  12/26/2017 16:18:44

3-----    Karen ---  07/18/2020 08:09:33

4 -----   Cher ---   09/23/2018 10:08:44

Please help me to group by year.

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`extract()`](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/SIkE2wnHyQBnU4AGWRZSRw) to extract the year from the date:

```
select extract(year from joining_on) as yyyy, count(*)
from t
group by extract(year from joining_on)
order by extract(year from joining_on);
```

Comment: Because I'm a big fan of less typing, Teradata allows you to use aliases in group by and order by clauses.